# linq getting key from list keyvalue pair

Tags: c#, linq

this is seems simple, but I have a list of keyvalue pairs  and a linq statement trying to get the the key, I dont understand why this dosent work Ex

```
   List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

list contains values: 1, test1 | 2, test2 | 3, test3 as data
my linq statement is:

```
string Key = list.AsEnumerable(x => x.Value == "test2").Select(x => x.Key).ToString();
```

seems simple enough to work but dosent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a single value's key, you'd do:

```
string Key = list.Single(x => x.Value == "test2").Key.ToString();
```

What you've written should not compile. `AsEnumerable()` does not have an overload taking a predicate.

If it did compile, it would almost certainly not give you what you intended as you're calling `ToString()` on an `IEnumerable<int>`, which would return that type's name and not the `Single()` value or `First()` value in the enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FirstOrDefault`

```
var pair = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "test2");
if(pair != null)
     string Key = pair.Key.ToString();
```

This is much safer than `First` and `Single` because it won't throw exception if there is no `KeyValuePair` with a given `Value` or there are more than one elements with a given Value.

Comment: Key is an int. `pair.Key.ToString()`

Comment: Note: Exceptions may or may not be wanted in this situation, but they shouldn't ever be called unsafe. If he's writing code that depends on always finding a Key for the given value, `First()` and `Single()` are exactly what he should use.

Comment: @CoryNelson yes,if you sure that value exists ofcourse First and Single can be used.I just told my opinion.I'm usually prefer FirstOrDefault over First. without exception handling First or Single shouldn't be used I guess.